# Assigning homepage layout based on community rather than profiles

Tags: community

We have a scenario where we have multiple communities enabled and there are users who are part of multiple communities. I understand that i can assign different home page layouts based on profiles.

We have different VF pages set up homepage for different communities based on profiles. But there are a few users who are part of multiple communities. So everytime these users login into different communities they see the same homepage which was set up for their profile. Is there way we directly set up a visualforce page as  home page for a particular community Or is there some way we can define homepage for a community rather than profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your communities have path defined, you can use the `$Site.prefix` global variable in the visual force page to determine which community is currently being accessed. And then you can use this to render the approriate VF pages.

The main page can contains different iframes which will be unique to each community

```
<!--mainVFPage-->
<apex:page>
   <apex:iframe src="/{!$Site.prefix}/communityone" rendered="{!IF($Site.Prefix=='CommuntiyOne',true,false)}"/>
   <apex:iframe src="/{!$Site.Prefix}/communityTwo" rendered="{!IF($Site.Prefix=='CommuntiyOne',true,false)}"/>
</apex:page>
```

I have not tried this myself but I think this should work!